# Plotting data together in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

i am new to R. I heard that R has awesome tools to plot the graphs. I have 3 data sets like this:

```
0.01 2
0.02 3
0.03 4
```

as file1.txt and

```
0.015 3
0.024 6 
0.34  56
```

as file2.txt.

I want to plot(for eg, in file1.txt, they are x and y axis entries: x=0.01,y=2,x=0.01,y=3,...) both file1.txt and file2.txt entries as a x-y graph, with both curves in the same graph. Can curves of file1.txt and file2.txt made in different colours? Please help! And is there a way to tag curve of file1.txt with for example, case1.,curve of file2.txt with case2, etc. I am asking many things, but please give me one example and i can learn from it.Thanks.

Comment: It's true, `R` does has awesome graphics capabilities, and what you want is within those capabilities. But it does require some effort. Generally, here you're expected to show some effort before asking your question. Show everyone what you've tried (edit your question to include code) and you'll probably get quick and detailed help to get you to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using `plot` and then `lines` for overlaying the graph. Use `col` for selecting different colors.

Try `?plot`, `?lines`, `?points`

Assuming you have read data into data frames,

```
file1=read.table(text="x y
0.01 2
0.02 3
0.03 4",header=T)

file2=read.table(text="x y
0.015 3
0.024 6 
0.34  56",header=T)


plot(file1$x, file1$y, col="red", type='l', xlim=c(0,0.5), ylim=c(0,100))
lines(file2$x, file2$y, col="blue")
```

Comment: why the second graph is line? why is it not curve like the first one?

Comment: both graphs are lines. may be its not clear because the outlier value of `56` in `file2`.